# Google script comparing sheet name is returning False when it should be returning True

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So I'm trying to get a google script to only work on a few sheets. However, it's not working right now. I tried logging the problem to see where it was going wrong, and I seem to have the exact same string being compared against itself, however, it's returning FALSE.

Code and logs:

```
function onEdit(e) {

    var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var activerange = e.range;
  var activeSheetName = activeSheet.getName()
  var ValidRange = {
    top : 3,
    bottom : 200,
    left: 4,
    right: 4,
  };
  var ThisColumn = activerange.getColumn


    Logger.log("active_range: " + activerange);
    Logger.log("active range col: " + activerange.getColumn + "active range row: " + activerange.getRow());
    Logger.log("active_range.value: " + activerange.getCell(1, 1).getValue());
    Logger.log("active_range. colidx: " + activerange.getColumnIndex());
    Logger.log("active sheet: " + activeSheetName);
  Logger.log("RWC Test: " + activeSheetName == "RWC CR's");
  Logger.log("STK Test: " + activeSheetName == "STK CR's");
  Logger.log("Comment Test: " + activeSheetName == "Comment Database");


  if (ThisColumn < activerange.left || ThisColumn > activerange.right) return;
  if (activeSheet.getName() == "RWC CR's" || activeSheet.getName() == "STK CR's" || activeSheet.getName() == "BTWD CR's"){
    var FormulaToUse = range.offset(0, -1).getformula();
   range.SetFormula = FormulaToUse
  };

}



function test_onEdit() {
  onEdit({
    user : Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
    source : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
    range : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell(),
    value : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell().getValue(),
    authMode : "LIMITED"
  });
}
```

Logs:

```
[18-05-29 12:44:31:226 PDT] active_range: Range  
[18-05-29 12:44:31:227 PDT] active range col: function getColumn() {/*
*/}  
active range row: 1  
[18-05-29 12:44:31:228 PDT] active_range.value: ID  
[18-05-29 12:44:31:229 PDT] active_range. colidx: 1  
[18-05-29 12:44:31:230 PDT] active sheet: Comment Database  
[18-05-29 12:44:31:230 PDT] false  
[18-05-29 12:44:31:231 PDT] false  
[18-05-29 12:44:31:231 PDT] false
```

Expected behavior: The 3rd False in the log should be True - "Comment Database" is the string being compared to the earlier "Comment Database", which should be returning "True", not "False"

Pardon me if I've made some type of silly language error, relatively new to google scripts

The goal is whenever someone enters data, it'll "store" the data using formulas somewhere else, the re-display the data where they entered it using a recursive formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

order of operations is your issue

You are doing this:

```
("Comment Test: " + activeSheetName) == "Comment Database"
```

You are adding the string to the variable and seeing if it equals something else so `"Comment Test: Comment Database"` is not going to equal `"Comment Database"`.

Change it to

```
Logger.log("Comment Test: " + (activeSheetName == "Comment Database"))
```

Comment: Yup, that worked. You answered so quickly that I can't accept the solution just yet!